# java tic tac toe user chooses board size and how many in a row to win (no GUI)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe

im making a tic tac toe game where the user can choose the the board size and how many in a row needed to win. for example a user can make the board 8*8 and say that you need 6 in a row to win. Everything is working fine except that i cant seem to get the winning condition diagonally to work. The first part is the main method. can anyone give me any tips or ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToeApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
TicTacToeGame game;
int size, need, player = 1;
String [] names = new String[2];
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter Player 1's name:  ");
names[0] = kbd.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter Player 2's name:  ");
names[1] = kbd.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter the TIC-TAC-TOE grid size:  ");
size = kbd.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter how many in a row you need to win:  ");
need = kbd.nextInt();
System.out.println();

game = new TicTacToeGame(size, need, names);

while (!game.haveWinner() && !game.isFull())
{
  player = (player + 1) % 2;
  game.playOneTurn(player);
}

if (game.isFull())
  System.out.println("It's a TIE!");
else
  System.out.println(names[player] + " is the winner!");

System.out.println("\nBye!");

} 

}
```

Above is the main method and below is the winning conditions and all the other code that makes it work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToeGame
{
Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in);
protected static char X='x';
protected static char O='o';
 int size;
int need;
String[] names;

char[][] game;
int x, y;
public TicTacToeGame(int size, int need, String [] names)
{
this.size=size;
this.need=need;
this.names=names;
game=new char[size][size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{ 
   for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
   game[i][j] = '-';
}
System.out.print(this);

 }

public String toString()
{
String theGame="\n";

  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<size;j++){    
          if(game[i][j]=='-')   
          theGame=theGame+'-';
        else if(game[i][j]=='o')   
           theGame=theGame+'o';
        else if(game[i][j]=='x')   
           theGame=theGame+'x';    
        }
            theGame=theGame+"\n";
        }        
  return theGame;
} 


public boolean haveWinner()
{

// what i tried doing was to comment out the horizontal and vertical winning conditions                                    and just tried the diagonal

int count=0;
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++)//horizontal
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
      {   
          if(game[i][j]==X)
             count++;
             if(game[i][j]!=X)
                count=0;
             if (count==need)
                return true;  
       }

  if(count!=need)//vertical
   count=0;       
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
      {   
          if(game[j][i]==X)
             count++;
             if(game[j][i]!=X)
                count=0;
             if (count==need)
                return true;  
       } 



  if (count!=need)
       count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
      for(int j =0; j < size; j++)
      {
          if(game[i][j] == X)
              count++;
          if(game[i][j] != X)
                  count=0;  
              if(game[i+1][j+1] == X)
                  count++;
         if(game[i+1][j+1] != X)
                  count=0;
          if(count ==need)
              return true;
      }


 return false;

  }

  public boolean isFull()
  {   
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){ 
  for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
     if(game[i][j]=='-')
        return false;
 }
 return true;
  }

  public void playOneTurn(int player){

   System.out.print("play "+names[player]+":");
   x=kbd.nextInt();
   y=kbd.nextInt();

  while(x >=size || y >=size){
  System.out.print("exception enter another move "+names[player]);
  x=kbd.nextInt();
  y=kbd.nextInt();
  }


  if(player==0){  
  if(game[x][y]=='-')
  game[x][y]='x';  
   System.out.print(this);

 }

 else if(player==1){ 
 if(game[x][y]=='-')
 game[x][y]='o'; 
 System.out.print(this);
 }


}
```

Comment: forgot to mention that i only was checking for X... i didnt bother doing the check winner for O. i will do that once i get X completely figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense to make haveWinner execute some recursive checks.

```
private boolean horizontal(int x,int y,int count) {
    bool result;
    if(count == need) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if(game[y][x] == X) {
            result = horizontal(x++,y,count++)
        } else {
            result = false;
        }
    } 
    return result;
}

vertical() ...
diagonal() ...

public boolean haveWinner(int x, int y, int count) {
    bool result;
    if(horizontal(x,y,0) || vertical(x,y,0) || diagonal(x,y,0)) {
        result = true;
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
}
```

You can design `vertical()` and `diagonal()` based on my implementation of `horizontal`.

With this system, you need to take into account the fact that it will check from left to right, so you will need to redesign parts of this to make sure you don't check the elements which would generate ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

You will also need to remember that `diagonal()` will need up and down methods.

And this only checks for X at the moment; O can't win.

---

This may be more complicated than required. If so, I am open to suggestions

Comment: i see what your saying but i just cant figure out how to do it diagonally. if im not mistaken there are 4 possible ways to win diagonally. 'if (game[i+1][j+1] == X || game[i-1][j-1] == X || game[i+1][j-1] == X || game[i-1][j+1] == X' i just dont know how to do it without getting out of bounds errors

Comment: There are really only two ways that you need to check for diagonals: to the right and up, and to the right and down. If you think about it, the other two that you listed (to the left and up, to the left and down) are actually just translations of the first two, with the opposite starting points (to the left and up == to the right and down, to the left and down == to the right and up).

As for the exceptions, you could `try` the checking code and `catch`  an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but this is an extremely crude solution.

Comment: The best solution would be to compute which elements are safe to check based on the `need` field and the width and height of the playing field.